# Generic Sybase stored procedure execution in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I'd like to execute Sybase stored procedure the same way I am doing in a SQL IDE, i.e. something like this in SQL:

```
exec sp_GetCMyDataPerRegion JAPAN'
```

However, instead of this, in the C# code I am forced to define each parameter individually, each having all those types defined:

```
AseCommand command = new AseCommand(spName, DbConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

AseParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@region";
param.AseDbType = AseDbType.VarChar;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = myValue;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Quite a pain and not finding anyway so far to have it "generic", i.e. would just like to wrap the store procedure call in a method with this kind of signature:

```
public AseDataReader ExecuteStoredProcedure(string spExecutionString){}
```

Would you have any way on doing so?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have an example of an SqlDataReader where the Function call is

```
ExecuteNonQuery("dbo.[Sp_Skp_UpdateFuncties]", parameters);
```

This is in a class DataBaseManager which hold the databaseconnectionstring

```
public classDataBaseManager
{
...
public int ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedprocedureNaam, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> parameters)
{
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
    {
        Connection = DatabaseConnectie.SqlConnection,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = storedprocedureNaam,
    };

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in parameters)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@" + keyValuePair.Key, Value = keyValuePair.Value ?? DBNull.Value }
        );
    }

    if (sqlCommand == null)
        throw new KoppelingException("Stored procedure ({0}) aanroepen lukt niet", storedprocedureNaam);
    return sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So you don't need to precise anymore the direction and the type of the parameter? I've tried with a command.ExecuteReader() but can't make it working

Comment: Actually could make it working by first creating a "AseParameter param = command.CreateParameter();", then defining the param details. thanks again!